# How to get week start date from week number in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have all week numbers from 20161 to 201640. I want to know what is the start date and end date of week 31.

How can I write query in postgresql to get that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To get the start date, simply convert the week number to a date using `to_date()`

If you are using [ISO week numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) use:

```
select to_date('201643', 'iyyyiw');
```

Otherwise use:

```
select to_date('201643', 'yyyyww');
```

Just add 6 days to resulting date to get the end date of the week: `to_date('201643', 'iyyyiw') + 6`

Comment: I love the simple query but postgres keeps giving me error message :(

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to_date"
LINE 1: to_date('201643', 'yyyyww')
        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "to_date"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1

Comment: @YOBOX  Well, you need to put that into a SELECT statement, you can't just run that like that

Comment: Beautiful solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date '2016-01-01' + interval '1 day' * ((7 - EXTRACT(DOW FROM DATE '2016-01-01')) + 29*7)     AS start_date,
       date '2016-01-01' + interval '1 day' * ((7 - EXTRACT(DOW FROM DATE '2016-01-01')) + 29*7 + 6) AS end_date,
```

Comment: Doesn't that assume that January first is the start of a week?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I (finally) updated my answer.  I think we can adjust the week to the first day of the year using `EXTRACT(DOW ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with weeks may be tricky if you allow the first and last weeks of the year to be less than 7 days long.

This is my two cents using ISO weeks (first day is monday, with dow = 1). They return the first and last date of a week out of the year and the week index.

Notice a year has 365/7 = 52,142857142857143 weeks, or 366/7 = 52,285714285714286 weeks, depending on its length. So, weeks always range in [0, 52]. I had to use an `if` for week 52 as it cannot be calculated as `7-d`.

```
create or replace function first_date_of_isoweek(y int, w int) 
returns date
language sql as $$
  select to_date(concat(y, to_char(w, 'fm00')), 'iyyyiw');
$$;

create or replace function last_date_of_isoweek(y int, w int) 
returns date
language plpgsql as $$
declare
  d1 date;
  d2 date;
  d smallint;
begin
  -- Calculate first date of an isoweek
  d1 =  to_date(concat(y, to_char(w, 'fm00')), 'iyyyiw');

  -- Year's last week needs an speacial treatment
  if w = 52 then
    return to_date(concat(y, '1231'), 'yyyyMMdd'); 
  else
    -- Calculate the dow of the first date
    d = extract(isodow from d1);
  
    -- Calculate the last date out of the first date
    return d1 + interval '1 day' * (7-d);
  end if;
end $$;
```

Test 2021 as follows:

```
select first_date_of_isoweek(2021, 0);

first_date_of_isoweek|
---------------------+
           2021-01-01|

select last_date_of_isoweek(2021, 0);

last_date_of_isoweek|
--------------------+
          2021-01-03|

select first_date_of_isoweek(2021, 1);

first_date_of_isoweek|
---------------------+
           2021-01-04|

select last_date_of_isoweek(2021, 1);

last_date_of_isoweek|
--------------------+
          2021-01-10|

select first_date_of_isoweek(2021, 52);

first_date_of_isoweek|
---------------------+
           2021-12-27|

select last_date_of_isoweek(2021, 52);

last_date_of_isoweek|
--------------------+
          2021-12-31|
```